# Children of Wrap widget not in the same line when overflowing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using Wrap widget to solve my overflow problems:

```
Wrap(
      children: [
        Text(subtitle, style: TextStyle(color: Color(COLOR_PRIMARY),fontSize: 12.5)),
        Image(
          image: AssetImage(
              drinkNameToImage[widget.post.cocktail] as String),
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
        )
      ],
    ),
```

And when my row of text doesn't overflow everything works fine and looks like this

[image]

But when the line overflows it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to have the image next to the text United States, how can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `Wrap` widget, it is having two `Text` and `Image` widgets and based on `wrap` nature it is working fine. Because while `Text` widget is taking full width, it will eventually go to next line.

`Text` widget is taking 1st two lines because it is not having enough spaces and after `United States` text, rest space is cover by `Text` widget. You can check it by widget-inspector, or simply wrap with a Container widget and provide color.

In your case you need to use `RichText` instead of `Wrap`.

```dart
 RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: subtitle,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          //color: Color(COLOR_PRIMARY),
                          fontSize: 12.5),
                    ),
                    WidgetSpan(
                        child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        drinkNameToImage[widget.post.cocktail] as String,
                      ),
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Check To learn more about [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)